# check if hash value of specific key contains specific value ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

I have hash with key and multiple values. now I have to check if specific value exists in that multiple values or not.

The stucture of my hash is like this...

```
@allinfo[hour_idx].push({"id" => w.id, "cat" => w.cat, "value" => w.value})
```

Now I want to check if id already exist for the allinfo[hour_idx] key. 
I am trying to use if(@allinfo.has_value?(w.id) but it is not working, which I guess becoz I am custom object of multiple values.

My main objective is not to have mulitple id's in values for specific key.
I hope I am clear what I except...Thanks

Thanks

Comment: .. is `@allinfo[hour_idx]` supposed to be a multidimensional array? or an array of hashes?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd change your data structure to be a hash instead of an array, and then you can use the `w.id` as a hash key for much simpler (and faster) checking.

Ie.

```
@allinfo[hour_idx] = {}
@allinfo[hour_idx][w.id] = { "cat" => w.cat, "value" => w.value }
```

You weren't clear on whether you wanted to overwrite existing `w.id` elements with new ones:

```
@allinfo[hour_idx][new.id] = { "cat" => new.cat, "value => new.value }
```

...or not add new ones if there was already an existing one:

```
@allinfo[hour_idx][new.id] ||= { "cat" => new.cat, "value => new.value }
```

If you want you could also continue to store the `"id" => w.id` element in the enclosed hashes, even though you're using the `w.id` for the outer key. Then you can get precisely the same array of hashes as you have currently with simply:

```
@allinfo[hour_idx].values
```